# Flexbox configuration

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have following html markup. I would like h1 tag to take full with of the page (100%) and three articles to appear in one row using **flexbox**. The image should shrink to fit the row if needed.

```css
#content {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

#content>h2 {
  flex: 0 1 100%;
}

#content>article {
  padding: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #cccc33;
  background: #dddd88;
  flex: 1 0 50%;
}
```

```html
<section id="content">
  <h2>Featured Work</h2>
  <article>
    <img src="http://placehold.it/450x450">
  </article>
  <article>
    <img src="http://placehold.it/450x450">
  </article>
  <article>
    <img src="http://placehold.it/450x450">
  </article>
</section>
```

Here is the jsfiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/fejt3m1s/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```css
#content {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-content: flex-start;  /* 1 */
  min-height: 800px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#content>h2 {
  flex: 0 0 100%;             /* 2 */
}

#content>article {
  flex: 1 0 30%;              /* 3 */
  text-align: center;
  padding: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #cccc33;
  background: #dddd88;
}

img {
  max-width: 100%;           /* 4 */
}
```

```html
<section id="content">
  <h2>Featured Work</h2>
  <article>
    <img src="http://placehold.it/350x350">
  </article>
  <article>
    <img src="http://placehold.it/350x350">
  </article>
  <article>
    <img src="http://placehold.it/350x350">
  </article>
</section>
```

Notes:

1. [Pack flex lines to the top of the container](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42613359/3597276) (otherwise you may get a gap between lines).
2. Make `h1` consume entire line, which forces subsequent items to create new lines.
3. Allow only three `article` elements per line. Each takes equal width.
4. Keep the image inside the flex item.

Answer (score 4):

You need to set `flex: 0 0 100%` on `h1` element and `max-width: 100%` on image elements.

```css
#content {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
#content>h1 {
  flex: 0 0 100%;
}
#content>article {
  padding: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #cccc33;
  background: #dddd88;
  flex: 1;
}
img {
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<section id="content">
  <h1>Featured Work</h1>
  <article>
    <img src="http://placehold.it/350x350">
  </article>
  <article>
    <img src="http://placehold.it/350x350">
  </article>
  <article>
    <img src="http://placehold.it/350x350">
  </article>
</section>
```

Answer (score 2):

Honestly, I would just place the `h1` tag outside of the flexbox. This makes things a whole lot simpler. Here's a working example:

```css
#content {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
}

#content>article {
    padding: 5px;
    border: 1px solid #cccc33;
    background: #dddd88;
    flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<h1>Featured Work</h1>

<section id="content">
  <article>
    <img src="http://placehold.it/350x350">
  </article>
  <article>
    <img src="http://placehold.it/350x350">
  </article>
  <article>
    <img src="http://placehold.it/350x350">
  </article>
</section>
```

**Edit:**

To fix the row problem, you can look at Nenad Vracar's solution below.