# Why align-self does not align items left and right?

Tags: html, css, sass, flexbox

Now what I want here is **.q-order-item-info** to be on the left side and **.q-order-item-quantity** to be on the right side, but somehow it does not happen, so what should I do to make it work?

My code is as shown below:

xyz.scss

```
.order-container {
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100vw;
    overflow-y: none;
    float: left;
    background-color: #f3f3f3;
    .q-background {
        float: left;
        width: 100%;
        height: 14.3vw;
        background: url("../../image/i-header-list.jpg") no-repeat;
        background-size: contain;
    }
    .q-text {
        position: relative;
        top: 2rem;
        font-size: 2rem;
        text-align: center;
    }
    .q-order-container {
        width: 100%;
        position: relative;
        padding-top: 20px;
        top: 2rem;
        height: 80%;
        .q-orders-div {
            position: relative;
            margin-left: 5rem;
            float: left;
            overflow: auto;
            width: 50%;
            height: 70%;
            background-color: #f3f3f3;
            .orders-tile {
                width: 90%;
                height: 20%;
                position: relative;
                margin-left: 3.5rem;
                background-color: #f3f3f3;
                .q-order-divider {
                    position: absolute;
                    margin-left: 5%;
                    bottom: 0;
                    width: 80%;
                    border-bottom: 1px solid #e7e7e7;
                }
            }
            .q-order-icon {
                position: relative;
                top: 50%;
                width: 4rem;
                height: 4rem;
                float: left;
                transform: translateY(-50%);
                background: url("../../image/ic_truck.png") no-repeat;
                background-size: contain;
            }
            .q-order-foodtruck-info {
                background-color: #f3f3f3;
                position: relative;
                margin-left: 2rem;
                width: 80%;
                float: left;
                top: 50%;
                transform: translateY(-50%);
                .q-order-foodtruck-name {
                    font-size: 1.2rem;
                    color: #345;
                }
                .q-order-time {
                    width: 100%;
                    .q-order-status-text {
                        font-size: 1.1rem;
                        float: left;
                        color: #345;
                    }
                    .q-order-divider-timing {
                        float: left;
                        position: relative;
                        margin-top: 2px;
                        margin-left: 1rem;
                        height: 10px;
                        width: 1.5px;
                        background-color: #cccccc;
                    }
                    .q-order-timing {
                        position: relative;
                        margin-left: 1rem;
                        font-size: 1.1rem;
                        float: left;
                        color: #345;
                    }
                }
            }
            .q-order-details {
                position: relative;
                top: 50%;
                transform: translateY(-50%);
                float: right;
                height: 20px;
                width: 20px;
                background: url("../../image/ic_details.png") no-repeat;
                background-size: contain;
            }
        }
    }
    .q-orders-status {
        position: relative;
        margin-top: 2rem;
        width: 42%;
        height: 60%;
        right: 3rem;
        float: right;
        background-color: #f3f3f3;
        overflow-y: auto;
        .q-order-rate {
            width: 100%;
            height: 5.5rem;
            background-color: #ffffff;
            box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px 1px #DBDBDB;
        }
        .q-order-info {
            position: relative;
            margin-top: 2rem;
            color: #ffffff;
            box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px 1px #DBDBDB;
            .q-order-item {
                width: 100%;
                background-color: #ffffff;
                display: flex;
                .q-order-item-info {
                    font-size: 1.3rem;
                    position: relative;
                    align-self: flex-start;
                    margin-left: 1rem;
                    color: #345;
                }
                .q-order-item-quantity {
                    font-size: 1.3rem;
                    position: relative;
                    align-self: flex-end;
                    margin-right: 1rem;
                    color: #345;
                }
            }
            .q-order-info-divider {
                position: absolute;
                margin-left: 5%;
                top: 0;
                width: 80%;
                border-bottom: 1px solid #e7e7e7;
            }
            .q-total-amount {
                width: 100%;
                height: 4rem;
                display: flex;
                justify-content: center;
                align-items: center;
                background-color: #ffffff;
                .q-order-total-amount-text {
                    background-color: #345;
                    color: #333333;
                }
                .q-order-price {
                    position: relative;
                    margin-left: 2rem;
                    background-color: #789;
                    width: 20%;
                    color: #41C27F;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

xyz.html

```
<div class='order-container'>
    <div class="q-background">
    </div>
    <div class="q-text">
        <div>ORDER HISTORY</div>
    </div>
    <div class="q-order-container">
        <div class="q-orders-div">
            <div class="orders-tile" ng-repeat="item in vm.orders" ng-click="vm.setOrderInfo(item)">
                <div class="q-order-divider" />
                <div class="q-order-icon"></div>
                <div class="q-order-foodtruck-info">
                    <div class="q-order-foodtruck-name">
                        {{item.foodtruck_id.foodtruck_name}}
                    </div>
                    <div class="q-order-time">
                        <div ng-switch="item.order_status">
                            <div style="color:#65A07C" class="q-order-status-text" ng-switch-when="0">
                                PLACED
                            </div>
                            <div style="color:#65A07C" class="q-order-status-text" ng-switch-when="1">
                                ACCEPTED
                            </div>
                            <div style="color:#65A07C" class="q-order-status-text" ng-switch-when="2">
                                COOKED
                            </div>
                            <div style="color:#F0B0B2" class="q-order-status-text" ng-switch-when="3">
                                CANCELLED
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="q-order-divider-timing">
                        </div>

                        <div class="q-order-timing">
                            {{item.order_time}}
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="q-order-details" />
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>

        <div class="q-orders-status">
            <div class="q-order-rate"></div>
            <div class="q-order-info" ng-model="vm.orderInfo">
                <div class="q-order-item" ng-repeat="item in vm.orderInfo.items">
                    <div class="q-order-item-info"> {{item.item_name}}</div>
                    <div class="q-order-item-quantity"> X {{item.item_quantity_ordered}}</div>
                </div>
                <div class="q-order-info-divider" />
                <div class="q-total-amount">
                    <div class="q-order-total-amount-text">TOTAL AMOUNT PAYABLE</div>
                    <div class="q-order-price"> $ {{vm.orderInfo.order_total}}</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: can you lay out your css a little more clearly, like that it's more difficult to follow... and why all the float lefts? get rid of them... most elements will go left unless specifically otherwise coded to..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is your flex container:

```
.q-order-item {
    display: flex;
    width: 100%;
}
```

These are your flex items:

```
.q-order-item-info {
   align-self: flex-start;
}

.q-order-item-quantity {
   align-self: flex-end;
}
```

The problem is pretty clear.

An initial setting on a flex container is `flex-direction: row`. This means that flex items will line up horizontally.

It also means that the *main axis* is horizontal and the *cross axis* is vertical.

The `align-self` property works only on the cross axis.

So while you're trying to align your elements left and right, `align-self` is trying to align your elements top and bottom.

Instead of `align-self`, use the `justify-content` property, which is designed for alignment on the main axis.

```
  .q-order-item {
    display: flex;
    width: 100%;
    justify-content: space-between; /* NEW */
  }
```

Learn more about flex alignment on the *main axis* here:

- [In CSS Flexbox, why are there no "justify-items" and "justify-self" properties?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32551291/3597276)

Learn more about flex alignment on the *cross axis* here:

- [How does flex-wrap work with align-self, align-items and align-content?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42613359/3597276)