# Add a top bar to a three-column flexbox layout (Implementing the Flex-wrap)

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have to build a **3-column Flex Layout** here on the [codepen](https://codepen.io/codeispoetry/pen/Pmyzro?editors=1100)

> But I need to add a black color top bar like this:

[image]

I have added a code, which is commented in the codepen.

I have to write a CSS for this so that the black color top bar appears. Don't know how to do this. May be some wrap property will be used or some reverse property. Please guide me.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

header,
footer,
.content {
  display: flex;
}

.content {
  justify-content: space-between;
  height: 75vh;
  max-width: 1500px;
  margin: auto;
}

.main {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  width: 70.5%;
}

.primary {
  width: 27%;
  background-color: yellow;
}

.article {
  background-color: blue;
  width: 71%;
  order: 2;
}

.secondary {
  background-color: pink;
  width: 25%;
  order: 1;
}

.footer {
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>The Fundamental Layout</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>

  <header>
    <h1>This is a Header Location</h1>
  </header>

  <div class="content">
    <main class="main">
      <!-- <div class="top">
                  The Top area
              </div> -->
      <aside class="secondary">
        The secondary Sidebar
      </aside>

      <article class="article">
      </article>
    </main>

    <aside class="primary">
      The Primary Sidebar
    </aside>
  </div>

  <footer class="footer">
    The Footer Area
  </footer>

  <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[**revised codepen**](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/aWRmyP?editors=1100)

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

header,
footer,
.content {
  display: flex;
}

.content {
  justify-content: space-between;
  height: 75vh;
  max-width: 1500px;
  margin: auto;
}

.main {
  flex: 0 0 70.5%;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.top {
  flex: 0 0 100%;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
}

.secondary {
  background-color: pink;
  flex: 0 0 25%;
  order: 1;
}

.article {
  background-color: blue;
  flex: 1;
  order: 2;
}

.primary {
  flex: 0 0 27%;
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <h1>This is a Header Location</h1>
</header>
<div class="content">
  <main class="main">
    <div class="top">The Top area</div>
    <aside class="secondary">The secondary Sidebar</aside>
    <article class="article"></article>
  </main>
  <aside class="primary">The Primary Sidebar</aside>
</div>
<footer class="footer">The Footer Area</footer>
```

Here's how the top bar is positioned:

1. `.top` is made 100% wide inside its container, `.main`, which is 70.5% wide in a larger container.
2. Because `.main` has `flex-wrap: wrap`, that forces the other two flex items, `.secondary` and `.article` to the next row.
3. The siblings are then sized to fit together on the second row.

Comment: But why the gap has disappeared between the pink and the blue one. It looks like you have deleted the justify-content: space-between; property.

Comment: I just wanted to show you the concept for the layout. Of course, you'll need to fine tune spaces, heights, widths, etc on your own.

Comment: Sir, I still could not understand how that bar goes up? because I am doing this for learning. which property shifted it upward?

Comment: what mistake I am doing that mine s not going upward, the black one → https://codepen.io/codeispoetry/pen/Pmyzro?editors=1100

Comment: Ah I see so basically it is this property → flex-wrap: wrap that forces in the next row → flex-wrap: wrap

Comment: If you have `flex-wrap: wrap`, and an item takes 100% of the space, that forces other items to new lines.

Comment: In your codepen above, you're just missing `flex-wrap: wrap` on `.main`. The default value is `nowrap`.

Comment: This discussion is quite enlightening for me. I have one more question → I have used this property to create a gap between pink and blue. How can I create a gap between the black and the other two column? I mean we have successfully created a gap between two column. How can we emulate the same between two rows with some flex property like "    justify-content: space-between;"  not by margin or padding? Yes, fixed that flex-wrap: wrap issue.

Comment: Set heights and use `align-content: space-between`: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/PmyGLp?editors=1100

Comment: Thanks, In the real world scenario such as a blog website. would this be real → .main > * { height: 47.5%;}

Comment: Thank you so much sir. I have bookmarked this as this was enlightening. Please encourages us new comers by upvoting us only if you think this post deserved upvoting.

Comment: Also, these two posts will help you better understand `flex-wrap`: [**here**](http://stackoverflow.com/q/42613359/3597276) and [**here**](http://stackoverflow.com/q/32551291/3597276)

Comment: Yeah, I was able to search them in your top posts. You came as a blessing today.