# Flex auto margins behave differently in Chrome and Safari

Tags: css, google-chrome, safari, flexbox

Open this page in Chrome and in Safari and we can see the difference.

In Safari the "Maths" keyword is not on the right side as in Chrome.

Also the widths of the `item-3` div is different in Chrome and in Safari.

My issue is that why it is different in Safari and what is the fix (I want CSS fix on the `item-3`).

`flex-wrap: wrap` is not a acceptable solution.

```css
.main-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 400px;
  height: 300px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.item-1 {
  display: flex;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}

.item-2 {
  display: flex;
  border: 1px solid green;
}

.item-3 {
  display: flex;
  margin-left: auto!important;
  border: 2px solid yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="main-container">
  <div class="item-1">Physics</div>
  <div class="item-2">Chemistry</div>
  <div class="item-3">Maths</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The width of `.item-3` is different than its siblings because `margin-left: auto` packs the flex item to the right side. That's normal behavior for flex auto margins.

The reason `margin-left` doesn't work in Safari is a mystery / bug.

However, for cross-browser support, there is a simple flex alternative to auto margins in this case: `align-self: flex-end`

```css
.main-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 400px;
  height: 300px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.item-1 {
  display: flex;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}

.item-2 {
  display: flex;
  border: 1px solid green;
}

.item-3 {
  display: flex;
  align-self: flex-end;  /* NEW */
  border: 2px solid yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="main-container">
  <div class="item-1">Physics</div>
  <div class="item-2">Chemistry</div>
  <div class="item-3"><span>Maths</span></div>
</div>
```

If you want `.item-3` to keep the full width of the container, then use `justify-content: flex-end`.

```css
.main-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 400px;
  height: 300px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.item-1 {
  display: flex;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}

.item-2 {
  display: flex;
  border: 1px solid green;
}

.item-3 {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;  /* NEW */
  border: 2px solid yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="main-container">
  <div class="item-1">Physics</div>
  <div class="item-2">Chemistry</div>
  <div class="item-3">Maths</div>
</div>
```

---

**How `align-self: flex-end` works**

With `align-self: flex-end` you're shifting `.item-3` along the *cross axis*  all the way to the right.

This works because the flex container (`.main-container`) has `flex-direction: column`, which makes the *main axis vertical and cross axis horizontal*.

---

**How `justify-content: flex-end` works**

With `justify-content: flex-end` you're shifting *the children* of `.item-3` along the *main axis* all the way to the right.

This works because `.item-3` is a flex container with `flex-direction: row` (by default), which makes the *main axis horizontal and cross axis vertical*.

Then, as per the specification, text in a flex container that is not explicitly wrapped by an element, is considered an anonymous flex item. This allows `justify-content` to work.

> [**4. Flex Items**](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#flex-items)
>
> Each in-flow child of a flex container becomes a flex item, and each
>   contiguous run of text that is directly contained inside a flex
>   container is wrapped in an anonymous flex item.

---

**Why `text-align: right` doesn't work**

`text-align: right` won't work because flex items (including anonymous ones) are considered block-level elements. The `text-align` property applies only to inline-level content.

---

**More information**

Learn more about flex alignment along the *main axis* here:

- [In CSS Flexbox, why are there no "justify-items" and "justify-self" properties?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32551291/3597276)

Learn more about flex alignment along the *cross axis* here:

- [How does flex-wrap work with align-self, align-items and align-content?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42613359/3597276)