# Make flex items go from bottom to top

Tags: html, css, flexbox

The following HTML and CSS creates a "bar chart". But the chart columns grow from top to bottom. How can I make them grow from bottom to top?

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-size: 0;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 50px;
}

.bar-chart {
  box-shadow: none;
  height: calc(50px * 3);
  width: calc(50px * 4);
}

.column {
  display: inline-flex;
  width: 100px;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  height: 150px;
}

.cell {
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 1px rgb(0, 0, 0);
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  font-size: 14pt;
}
```

```html
<figure class="bar-chart">
  <div class="column">
    <div class="cell">one</div>
    <div class="cell">two</div>
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <div class="cell">three</div>
    <div class="cell">four</div>
    <div class="cell">five</div>
    <div class="cell">six</div>
    <div class="cell">seven</div>
    <div class="cell">eight</div>
  </div>
</figure>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of `flex-wrap: wrap`, use `flex-wrap: wrap-reverse`.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-size: 0;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 50px;
}

.bar-chart {
  box-shadow: none;
  height: calc(50px * 3);
  width: calc(50px * 4);
}

.column {
  display: inline-flex;
  width: 100px;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap-reverse;  /* ADJUSTED */
  height: 150px;
}

.cell {
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 1px rgb(0, 0, 0);
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  font-size: 14pt;
}
```

```html
<figure class="bar-chart">
  <div class="column">
    <div class="cell">one</div>
    <div class="cell">two</div>
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <div class="cell">three</div>
    <div class="cell">four</div>
    <div class="cell">five</div>
    <div class="cell">six</div>
    <div class="cell">seven</div>
    <div class="cell">eight</div>
  </div>
</figure>
```

---

With `wrap-reverse` the cross-start and cross-end directions are switched.

In a row-direction container, this refers to the top and bottom (see the image below).

*From the spec:*

> [**5.2. Flex Line Wrapping: the `flex-wrap`
>   property**](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#flex-wrap-property)
>
> For the values that are not `wrap-reverse`, the cross-start direction
>   is equivalent to either the inline-start or block-start direction of
>   the current writing mode (whichever is in the cross axis) and the
>   cross-end direction is the opposite direction of cross-start.
>
> When `flex-wrap` is `wrap-reverse`, the cross-start and cross-end
>   directions are swapped.

[image]

<sup>Source: [W3C](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#box-model)</sup>

---

Learn more about flex alignment along the *main axis* here:

- [In CSS Flexbox, why are there no "justify-items" and "justify-self" properties?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32551291/3597276)

Learn more about flex alignment along the *cross axis* here:

- [How does flex-wrap work with align-self, align-items and align-content?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42613359/3597276)