# Why isn't this element centering?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm asking this for a class assignment I'm working on, and somehow I've broken CSS so bad that even my teacher is stumped.

```css
body {
  font-family: Georgia, serif;
  background: url("graphics/Background.png");
  margin: 5%;
}

h1 {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0px 0px 20px 0px;
}

.panel {
  border: 3px solid black;
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  margin: 20px;
}

#container {
  display: flex;
  align-content: space-between;
  justify-content: center;
  background-color: red;
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

````html
<h1>Sunday Funnies</h1>
<div id="container">
  <img class="panel" src="Graphics/placeholder.png">
  <img class="panel" src="Graphics/placeholder.png">
</div>
</div>

```
````

This is what I have after my professor did some tinkering to try and figure out what was going on.

Answer (score 2):

`align-content` targets flex lines, not flex items.

You need to use `align-items`.

Plus, `align-content` has no effect in a single-line flex container (i.e., `flex-wrap: nowrap`).

```css
h1 {
  text-align: center;
}

#container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  background-color: red;
}

.panel {
  border: 3px solid black;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 20px;
}
```

```html
<h1>Sunday Funnies</h1>
<div id="container">
  <img class="panel" src="http://i.imgur.com/60PVLis.png">
  <img class="panel" src="http://i.imgur.com/60PVLis.png">
</div>
```

---

Here's a detailed explanation of cross-axis alignment:

- [How does flex-wrap work with align-self, align-items and align-content?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42613359/3597276)

---

*From the flexbox spec:*

> [**§ 8.4. Packing Flex Lines: the `align-content`
>   property**](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#align-content-property)
>
> The `align-content` property aligns a flex container’s lines within
>   the flex container when there is extra space in the cross-axis,
>   similar to how `justify-content` aligns individual items within the
>   main-axis. **Note, this property has no effect on a single-line flex
>   container.**

<sup>(emphasis mine)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

1. You want `align-items`, **not** `align-content`
2. `justify-content` refers to the main axis, whereas `align-items` refers to the cross-axis. This means that you likely want `align-items: center` if your intention is to center the items horizontally.

```css
body {
  font-family: Georgia, serif;
  background: url("graphics/Background.png");
  margin: 5%;
}

h1 {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0px 0px 20px 0px;
}

.panel {
  border: 3px solid black;
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  margin: 20px;
}

#container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  background-color: red;
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

```html
<h1>Sunday Funnies</h1>
<div id="container">
  <img class="panel" src="Graphics/placeholder.png">
  <img class="panel" src="Graphics/placeholder.png">
</div>
```