# Flex-end does not push a view all the way to the bottom

Tags: css, react-native, flexbox

I'm trying to use flex box to put a view on the bottom of the screen.

I have a `HomeScreen` (which contains the button), The `HomeScreen` component is being set on `App.js` `NavigationContainer`.

I set the `HomeScreen` to `display:"flex"` and gave the `HomeScreen` itself `flex: 1`, However, when I set my `FloatingButton` to be `alignSelf: "flex-end"`, it does not go to the bottom of the screen.

This is a snack link with the relevant code: https://snack.expo.io/VVQZAPoej

This is how it is right now:

[image]

I set the background to be dark, so I can see that the `HomeScreen` does indeed takes the whole screen height.

Comment: Can't reproduce the problem in the snack link you provided. Getting error messages.

Comment: @MichaelBenjamin I'm sorry, this is only the relevant code, the errors occur because there are missing components that I didn't upload. I'm sorry, I forgot to remove the `body` but I don't use it.

Comment: @MichaelBenjamin I added the border to homeContainer, and it does wraps the whole screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In standard CSS the default `flex-direction` is `row`. But in React the default is `column`.

Therefore, `align-self`, which operates along the cross axis, is attempting to shift your button horizontally. You need it to shift vertically.

Either switch to row-direction, use an `auto` margin, or use `justify-content: space-between`.

References:

- [React Native documentation: `flex-direction`](https://reactnative.dev/docs/flexbox.html#flex-direction)
- [Methods for Aligning Flex Items along the Main Axis](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33856609/3597276)
- [Methods for Aligning Flex Items along the Cross Axis](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42888700/3597276)