# align only one link on the right, flex-end not working

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have this row of items I'm displaying at the top of the page but I'm not quite sure how to get one of them to appear at the far right. The rest are aligned to the left. I tried `align-self: flex-end` but that's not working. Here's the code:

```css
.wrapper {
    display:flex;
    justify-content:flex-start;
    align-items:flex-start;
}

a.nav, .search, .query {
    display:inline-block;
} 

.nav {
    margin-left:25px;
}

.nav a {
    margin-right:15px;
    color:#515949;
    transition:0.3s ease;
}

.nav a:hover {
    color:#33382d;
}

.link-right {
    align-self:flex-end;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
<div class="nav">
<a href="/" title="link"><span class="lnr lnr-arrow-left"></span></a> 
<a href="/" title="link"><span class="lnr lnr-envelope"></span></a> 
<a href="/" title="link"><span class="lnr lnr-link"></span></a>

<form class="search" action="javascript:return false">
<input type="text" class="query" placeholder="search..."></form>
</div>
<a href="/" class="link-right" title="link"><span class="lnr lnr-plus-circle"></span></a>
</div>
```

The link with the class link-right is the one I'm trying to get on the right. I don't know if this makes a difference but as you can see there's also a search bar next to the links, also going on the left. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The `align-self` property is designed for alignment on the cross axis.

When you're in `flex-direction: row` (the default setting), the cross axis is vertical.

Therefore, `align-self: flex-end` is trying to pin your item to the bottom, not the right. Since there's no extra vertical space, there's no place for it to go, and nothing happens.

Try using flex `auto` margins in this case.

This is really all you need:

```css
nav {
  display: flex;
}

a {
  margin-right: 15px;
}

a:last-child {
  margin-left: auto;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <a href="/" title="link">ONE</a>
  <a href="/" title="link">TWO</a>
  <a href="/" title="link">THREE</a>
  <form class="search" action="javascript:return false">
    <input type="text" class="query" placeholder="search...">
  </form>
  <a href="/" title="link">FIVE</a>
</nav>
```

Learn more about flex alignment along the *cross axis* here:

- [How does flex-wrap work with align-self, align-items and align-content?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42613359/3597276)

Learn more about flex alignment along the *main axis* here:

- [In CSS Flexbox, why are there no "justify-items" and "justify-self" properties?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32551291/3597276)

Answer (score -1):

I fixed it for you :)

In `.wrapper` class all you gotta do is change `justify-content : flex-end;` to `justify-content : space-between;`, and set `align-items : center;`.

Just replace your `css` with this :

```
.wrapper {
  display:flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items : center;
}

a.nav, .search, .query {
  display:inline-block;
} 

.nav {
  margin-left:25px;
}

.nav a {
  margin-right:15px;
  color:#515949;
  transition:0.3s ease;
}

.nav a:hover {
  color:#33382d;
}
```

Let me know if it worked :)

Comment: Hi, thank you! It worked, but for some reason now the link on the right is higher up than everything else? Is there a way to fix that?

Comment: Sure thing :) Add this on start of your css : *{

  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;

}

Comment: Hey, so sorry to keep bothering you about this but that doesn't seem to have worked :( it only messed with the margins I was using and the link didn't align

Comment: Not a problem friend, here you go, just copy the HTML and CSS from my codepen : https://codepen.io/Juka99/pen/GRjErKd

Let me know if it works now :)

Comment: The problem was your form tag, I removed it, and now everything works as it should. If you only have a search bar, or some type of input field, but no submit button, there is no reason to wrap it inside a form tag. You can just leave it without a form tag, and then code what will that field to in JavaScript :)