# Show a list of item inside a container with full height

Tags: javascript, css

I've a div container (the grey one), with contains some children with a `flex` display. The container can scroll vertically.

The height of the gray container should be the same as the window.

```css
.container {
  width: 500px;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: lightgrey;
  padding: 10px;
  overflow: auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.item {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: gold;
  border: 1px solid orange;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item" ></div>
  <div class="item" ></div>
  <div class="item" ></div>
  <div class="item" ></div>
  <div class="item" ></div>
  <div class="item" ></div>
  <div class="item" ></div>
</div>
```

If you run the snippet, you can see the result: each item is near another item and the container scrolls.

The problem is that if I remove some items (their number is dynamic), there is extra space between items. Why?

[image]

I don't want this extra space, how can I "remove" it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using `flex-wrap: wrap`, the contents are grouped into "lines" of contents known as [flex lines](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#flex-lines), the `align-content` property controls how the flex lines are packed.  In your case, setting `align-content: flex-start;` would achieve your needs.

[image: visualization of align-content settings]

<sup>Source [W3C](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#propdef-align-content)</sup>

```css
.container {
  width: 500px;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: lightgrey;
  padding: 10px;
  overflow: auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-content: flex-start;
}

.item {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: gold;
  border: 1px solid orange;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item" ></div>
  <div class="item" ></div>
  <div class="item" ></div>
  <div class="item" ></div>
  <div class="item" ></div>
  <div class="item" ></div>
  <div class="item" ></div>
</div>
```

Credit: This answer is inspired by another Stack Overflow post [How does flex-wrap work with align-self,align-items and align-content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42613359/how-does-flex-wrap-work-with-align-self-align-items-and-align-content)

Answer (score 0):

Because `container` height is 100vh. if you update it like `height:auto`, this issue will be fixed. Or items list should be wrapped by another element like below code. it's working

```css
.container {
  width: 500px;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: lightgrey;
  padding: 10px;
  overflow: auto;
}

.items {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.item {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: gold;
  border: 1px solid orange;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="items">
    <div class="item" ></div>
    <div class="item" ></div>
    <div class="item" ></div>
    <div class="item" ></div>
    <div class="item" ></div>
    <div class="item" ></div>
    <div class="item" ></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Ok, but its height should be the same as the window

Comment: @whitecircle then as my updated codes, items elements should be wrapped by another element

Comment: @RomanGavrilov, adding an inner layer helps remove extra spaces between lines; on the other hand, with `align-contents: flex-start`, it achieves the same without the need of additional layer.